compiling ntfs-3g on OS X: cannot find libgcrypt
I am compiling ntfs-3g on OS X (Ventura 13.6.6). When I run ./autogen.sh -vi I get the following error:
configure.ac:338: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_PATH_LIBGCRYPT

autoreconf cannot find the library libgcrypt that I installed through brew brew install libgcrypt and that is in /usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.10.3. I think something is wrong with path to libraries but I do not know what.
I have tried to comment out the part related to enable-crypto in configure.ac file, and it works, but I am not sure if I am going to need that part in the future.
I compile successfully with
./autogen.sh -vi
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -lintl" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/share/man --exec_prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

(excluding libgcrypt library in configure.ac)

I added the path to the libgcrypt m4 file, and compiled successfully like this
autoreconf -fiv  -I /usr/local/Cellar/libgcrypt/1.10.3/share/aclocal/
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/lib -lintl" ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/share/man --exec_prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install

The HD is writable and I can write to it, even if I have errors with rsync and  cp
rsync: mkstemp <destination> failed: Operation not permitted (1)

cp: <origin>: could not copy extended attributes to <destination>: Operation not supported on socket
cp: utimensat: <destination>: Permission denied
cp: fchmod: <destination>: Operation not permitted

